# Why does declaring an interface method that receives a base interface not allow implementations to receive an extension of this type?

Tags: c#

Compilation error says:

'SomeClass' does not implement 'IApply.Apply(IBase)'

```
public interface IBase {}
public interface IChildInterface : IBase
{
    void APublicMethod();
}

public interface IApply
{
    void Apply(IBase b);
}

public class SomeClass : IApply 
{
    public void Apply (IChildInterface i) <<-- compilation
    {                                          error
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read [ask] if you're surprised that a question can't consist of just code. You'll have to explain your expectations and show your research, "self-explanatory" code isn't that self-explanatory to others in general.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wouldn't expect somebody to answer the question if they couldn't read this simple code in the first place.

Comment: There's no need to get passive agressive. :) See the duplicates for your answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Those are not exactly duplicates. They suggest workarounds for the situation, but this question asks *why* it is like that. Answers here would either explain a (technical/logical) reason why it cannot possibly work like that, or state that it *could* work, but just is not a part of the language.

Comment: @O.R. a "why" question is useless, because its answer always is "because the language was designed that way".

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand completely what you are saying but I don't think I would have been able to describe the issue any more in the description than I already had written in the title. Next time i'll just copy and paste the title into the description and wait for someone to complain that I shouldn't write the same thing twice :)

Comment: @Alex if you refuse to give any background information so others can understand what you're trying to do and also that later Googlers can find your question on those terms, this may not be the site for you. You could start by explaining why you want to do this, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sorry, but that is nonsense. Certain restrictions have technical or logical reasons, while others do not. And in the former case, it is always better to understand *why* a restriction is imposed the way it is, rather than just mindlessly memorize a set of seemingly arbitrary rules.

Comment: @O.R. and then we're back at square one: the OP should explain what they're looking for. The technical background (or the "why") is explained in many duplicate Q&As. Again, a mere "why" always comes down to "because the language was designed that way", no spec of nonsense in that. If you want to know _why the language designers decided to do so_, sure, but then **mention that in your question**, or you're only going to get workarounds posted as answers. QED below.

Comment: @CodeCaster: "If you want to know *why the language designers decided to do so*, sure, but then **mention that in your question**" - I thought that's exactly what a "why" question does.

Comment: @O.R. 9 out of 10 cases it doesn't, and they genuinely ask _"Why can't I do this?"_ - _"Well, because the compiler tells you you can't, you have to fix your code"_ - _"Oh, okay"_. But I've been trying to tell the OP that, but they're not interested in editing their question, so I'm going to leave this as it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public interface IBase {}
public interface IChildInterface : IBase
{
    void APublicMethod();
}

public interface IApply<in T> where T: IBase
{
    void Apply(T b);
}

public class SomeClass : IApply<IChildInterface>
{
    public void Apply (IChildInterface i)
    {                                          
    }
}
```